# Love riddle - What am I?

Tags: riddle

First he chose me,
then we touched lips,
I was giving up everything up for him, and he loved me.

My life then turned upside down.
Without warning I was crushed and thrown out.

What am i?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you a

> Soda can?

First he chose me, then we touched lips,

> The person drinking the soda chose a can and lifted it to his lips in order to drink it

I was giving up everything up for him, and he loved me.

> The soda can gave up all its contents (the soda within), and the person drinking it was happy.

My life then turned upside down.

> The person drinking the soda turned the can upside down to get the last drops of soda.

Without warning I was crushed and thrown out.

> Once empty, the can was flattened in order to be put into the garbage.

Answer (score 3):

> Could it be some form of food (perhaps a love heart - linking to the question - or some other small food - like a cherry) that is chosen to be eaten, touches the lips as it's eaten, crunched and turned upside down as it's chewed and then crushed as thrown out *into your throat*.

---

> The "he loved me bit" could link to how much the consumer liked the item of food, which was willing to give up everything (be eaten, digested, etc.) for the consumer.